# Pairing libraries with header files

Tags: c++, sockets

I know what .h, .dll, and .lib files do and how they work together. I say that because the question seems to be asked and answered frequently, and it's not my question. I need to know how to find out which library file goes with which .h file.  For example, if I #include winsock2.h, on my first build I get lots of errors - obviously missing the library that goes with winsock2.h.  The only way I could find that it was ws2_32.lib was to search online.  There must be another way.

Comment: I clicked the wrong box: my question is for C++ not Java.

Comment: I clicked the wrong box: my question is for C++ not Java.

Comment: Fixed the tags for you. Well, you can just run `nm` (or whatever its Windows counterpart is) to find out the symbol names in a library, then grep for those in all header files.

Comment: If you're including headers, you should be looking at the documentation to see which library it needs, if any. In the case of Winsock2.h (and all libraries that ship with Windows), the MSDN tells you which library to link with on almost every documentation page.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to look at the documentation as the header file itself does not contain such information. At the same time you already should have needed the documentation to find the name of the header file.

At the bottom of every MSDN page you find a table with the fields "Header", "Library" and "DLL".

Example for `socket` function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx

[image: msdn]

Answer (score 1):

What I had hoped to find was something from Microsoft that installs with the SDK (or Visual Studio) and gives relations between header and library files in the SDK.  I realize there's not a one to one correspondence.  Even so ...

I give up.  I'm now confident that I'm not overlooking something obvious.  That is, my answer is that there's no answer.

I often try to reuse or evaluate software where someone else has decided what header files to include.  There's no documentation.  One recourse, the fastest, is an online search: MSDN or some search engine.  I spend much of my time disconnected, for a number of reasons, so that's often not a choice.  What I usually do then is grep the library directory for function names in the header - not perfect but it does the job.

Thanks, dudes (dudettes?) for your help